# Python prints different value each iteration but value is not changed.

Tags: python

I cannot wrap my head around why my python code acts in a certain way.

Since I do not change "current" the output should be the same for each iteration? This is a problem because I need "current" to be the same so each Node is generated from the same start-value.

See the following code:

tester.py

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, board=None):
        self.board = board

    def getBoard(self):
        return self.board

    def swap(self, xPos, yPos): # swap with zero

        for a in self.board:
            if 0 in a:
                self.board[self.board.index(a)][a.index(0)] = self.board[xPos][yPos]

        self.board[xPos][yPos] = 0

open = []

def gen_nodes(current):

    for i in [7, 15, 11]:

        print(current) # <-- why does this print a different value each time?

        new = Node(current)

        for a in new.getBoard():
            if i in a:
                xPos = new.getBoard().index(a)
                yPos = a.index(i)

        new.swap(xPos, yPos)

        open.append(new)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen_nodes([[1,   2,  3,  4],
               [8,   5,  6,  7],
               [9,   10, 11, 0],
               [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 0], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8, 5, 6, 0], [9, 10, 11, 7], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8, 5, 6, 15], [9, 10, 11, 7], [12, 13, 14, 0]]
```

Comment: according to a quick debug session I just made, the problem is in `new.swap(xPos, yPos)`. I mean, this is where `current` changes. still trying to figure out what is exactly happening..

Comment: `def getBoard(self):` this isn't Java. Don't make getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, that you save a reference to the array in `current` inside the `board` variable in Node. This way, when you call `swap`, this array is changed. Instead, you probably want a new copy of the array in every node, you can use `copy.deepcopy(node)` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a variable that points to a list to another variable doesn't mean to *copy* the list.

`new = Node(current)` creates an object of type `Node` whose `self.board` points to the same list as `current`, so whenever you modify `new`, `current` is also modified.

To avoid this, use the following:

```
from copy import copy

new = Node(copy(current))
```

Comment: I was going to say the same ;)